# Pull to refresh not working in iOS WebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, pull-to-refresh

I've implemented a straight forward `WKWebView` in iOS.

```
   var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refreshWebView"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

This is in `viewDidLoad()`

And the corresponding `refreshWebView` function. But when I run it on mobile or simulator, no matter how much I drag, there is no pull to refresh action. Nothing is triggered, and it almost feels like I am stuck to the upper bounds of the screen. Where can be going wrong?

Comment: Kindly run view will appear in webView(I mean the block which is loading the view). Do this in your **refreshWebView()** method

Comment: refreshWebView never gets called.

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 11):

Try to change your code like this, If you want to pull to `refresh` the `webView` you need to `addSubView` `UIRefreshControl` object in the `ScrollView` of `webView` like this

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshWebView(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Add func like this

```
func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("refersh")
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!))
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Have you added function, I have edited the answer and which swift you are using, swift 2 , swift 2.2 or greater?

Comment: Sorry, tried that, and still nothing. The "refresh" is just never printed. And somehow feels like it is just not being triggered.

Comment: You need to change your selector syntax. Check my edit for addTarget, Change your code like this

Comment: I am sorry, but nothing again. The print is never called.

Comment: Can you edit your question with  new code. Add whole code that you have try.

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 4 Solution** (Based on *Nirav D* answer)

You can simply call this setup method in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
private func setupRefreshControl() {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

@objc
private func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("refreshing...")
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: This works — add this before viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, and then call setupRefreshControl() within viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 4):

Just to say looking at this in Swift 3 and the answer from JAck helped me solve this issue:

in loadView()/viewDidLoad()

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = true
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

and then a separate function

```
func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("refersh")
    //
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

And I'm now seeing the refresh being printed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable bouncing for the scrollview of the webview:

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = true
```

This will let you drag the webview down which will trigger your UIRefreshControl.

Comment: If we enable bounces then it will bounce all side but the requirement is only top.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will put the refresh control in scrollview of webview.Initially it will load google.com. To see pull to refresh clearly I have set white color to the background of scroll view so it is clearly visible and on pull to refresh webview opens facebook page.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl.init()
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action:#selector(refreshControlClicked), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    self.webView.scrollView.addSubview(self.refreshControl!)

    self.webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.webView.delegate = self


    let url:URL = URL.init(string:"https://www.google.com")!

    self.loadRequestWithUrl(URLRequest.init(url: url))

}


func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    NSLog("website loaded")
}

func loadRequestWithUrl(_ urlRequest : URLRequest?){

    if(urlRequest != nil){

        self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest!)
    }
}

func refreshControlClicked(){

    let url:URL = URL.init(string:"https://www.facebook.com")!

    self.loadRequestWithUrl(URLRequest.init(url: url))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare this like below.

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourViewController.refreshWebView), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Hope this works..