# How do I use UIWebview pull to refresh in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I made a webview app but, I can't pull to refresh.
How can I do?
This is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.vicco.com.tr/report/")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    viewTwo.loadRequest(request);
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156954/pull-to-refresh-not-working-in-ios-webview/

Comment: This link may you help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256448/how-do-i-add-pull-to-refresh-in-webview

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try this for swift

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        webViewPDF.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("refersh")
        self.webViewPDF.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Comment: this is code not working with switf :(

Comment: Please check Swift 3.0 code it's working fine in swift